# vb.net Public Shared String loose value when open second form

Tags: vb.net, variables, shared

I'm declaring two strings into my main form this way:

```
Public Shared SerNum As String = vbNullString
Public Shared SKey As String = vbNullString
```

Then I give some values to them. After that, I open another form and I try to get values from the two variables but only `SerNum` preserves his value while `SKey` turns out to be `Nothing`.

I repeatedly checked my code but I didn't found a reason for this to happen.
The second form is showed immediatly after giving values.
What can I check to find the error?

At the moment I solved by using a `Public Shared Dictionary(of String, String)` and putting both strings into it, but I would like to understand where I'm wrong.

**EDIT**
I found the mistake: `SKey` was also declared into my `sub` so the value wasn't assigned to the `Public Shared variable` but to the `local variable`.
I thought I had 'commented' that row...

Comment: Can you share same code ?

Comment: @BeldiAnouar The whole code?

Comment: Something must be setting SKey to Null

Comment: @genespos no just when you call the seconde form

Answer (score 0):

I have a proposition for acceding to your variable from other form :
In From main let's name it "From1" must be like :

```
Public Class Form1
    Public SerNum As String = vbNullString
    Public SKey As String = vbNullString


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fr As New Form2(Me)
        SerNum = "ValueNum"
        SKey = "ValueKey"
        fr.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

In your seconde from "Form2" :

```
Public Class Form2
    Dim fr As New Form1
    Public Sub New(fr As Form1)
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.fr = fr
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        MsgBox(fr.SKey)
        MsgBox(fr.SerNum)
     End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your logic (I'm not a pro). Maybe in the future I'll decide to use your approach. ;)